# MongoDB: Increasing read speed on a single machine

Tags: mongodb

I use MongoDB to store price events for stocks. Depending on what you want to screen, the number of event can rapidly grow to 1Go-2Go.

I run MongoDB on a single machine and it is taking longer and longer to load the data. I am not able to find a clear answer on the web if "sharding on a single server" is a benefit to read speed.

Is it the right path to increase the read speed?

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults    locked db
     0      1    395      0       1     395       0  63.9g   128g  2.53g   7484 prices:70.5%
     0      0  14726      0       5   14728       0  63.9g   128g  2.48g  31555  prices:7.4%
     0      0      0      0       0       1       0  63.9g   128g  2.48g    436  prices:0.0%
     0      0      0      0       1       1       0  63.9g   128g  2.48g      0  prices:0.0%
     0      0      0      0       0       1       1  63.9g   128g  2.49g   3877      .:83.9%
     0      0      0      0       0       1       0  63.9g   128g  2.49g      0  prices:0.0%
```

Comment: hell no, sharding on a single machine would be completely pointless

Comment: Is there any direction you could point me to

Comment: Well first I would look to see what queries your doing and if they are using indexes right, next I would check that your working set fits and that your not getting too many page faults

Comment: How would you check page faults?

Comment: mognostat: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/ can be a good tool to use here, with a tutorial: https://blog.serverdensity.com/mongodb-monitoring-mongostat/

Comment: Sammaye, I get a lot of faults on updates. Does it mean I have some write that do not reach the database? What is the behaviour of MongoDB in this case?

Comment: In this case it means that the OS is having to page in a lot of `mongod`s data from disk, every page fault is a disk read, it means that your working set is not fitting very well into RAM and killing your performance. Are you sure all your queries use indexes if so then the next thing is to look at server stats

Comment: I use indexes. How can i look at the server stats? What to look at? Edit: I get faults on query, getmore etc also now. I have added mongostats in the main question

Comment: Ok first thing I would do is measure your working set, there are a couple of ways to do this, one would be to use the new working set analyzer within MongoDB itself: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#server-status-workingset and graph that for 10 mins where the database is slow, after compare that to how much memory you have and see if it fits

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using, and on what O/S?

Comment: mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.2.2 on windows 7  (64bit)